# Access Array-Value of constant in abstract class through smarty

Tags: php, smarty, abstract-class

I have an included abstract PHP-Class with some constants. One of these is an array. I want to access one value of it in a smarty template.

I achieved it like this:

```
{assign var=myConst value=abstractCls::arrName}
{$myConst.arrKey}
```

I'd rather have a "one-liner" like

```
{abstractCls::arrName.arrKey}
```

But that isn't working. Is there any other solution?

I'm aware that it would be easier to assign it to smarty in PHP, but than again I'd end up with a lot more code in different files.

Comment: does Smarty have getter/setter functions? Not familiar with what Smarty is, but I could just do `$class->getMyArray()`, have the array, or `$class->getMyArray()['my_value']`

Comment: Smarty is a PHP-template-engine with it's own syntax. Arrayvalues are accessed like this: {$arr.arrKey}. So you're suggestion doesn't really work.

Comment: Seems super weird.. I'll look into it, see if it's any good ;) but yeah that's fine, just seeing if you could still use vanilla PHP